# intellij highlights mode as invalid option in webpack config

Tags: intellij-idea, webpack

Intellij shows me following tooltip text on specifiying `mode: "production"` in my webpack.config.js. I think its due to some plugin but unable to identify which one.

> webpack: Property 'mode' is not allowed Validates options in the
>   webpack configuration file (which name should start with `webpack`,
>   e.g. `webpack.config.js`) against webpack Options Schema.
>
> Disable this inspection to turn off validation and code completions
>   inside the configuration object.

Note: I am using webpack 4.12.2.

Comment: Could you please try to disable custom plugins ("Settings | Plugins - Show custom")